# How do I disable "test plan" enforcement in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

`arc diff` rejects the commit if no test plan is specified. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 18):

Set `differential.show-test-plan-field` or `differential.require-test-plan-field` in your configuration.

Comment: This is done on the server: cd /path/to/phabricator && bin/config set differential.require-test-plan-field false