# arc diff disable Test Plan 'differential.require-test-plan-field' not working

Tags: git, automatic-ref-counting, phabricator

Trying to disable the required "Test Plan: " filed on `arc diff`.
 Tried the suggestions in: [How do I disable “test plan” enforcement in Phabricator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598026/how-do-i-disable-test-plan-enforcement-in-phabricator)

So my `.arcconfig` contains:

    `"differential.require-test-plan-field" : false, 
    "differential.show-test-plan-field" :  false,
    "base" : "git:merge-base(origin/master), arc:prompt"`

But when I run `arc diff --create` not only is the "Test Plan" field there.
If I try to submit the commit it throws an exception, saying that the test plan is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arcanist is a command-line interface to the Phabricator system. And it's not Arcanist that's insisting you supply a test plan - it's Phabricator. Phabricator's the server, so it gets to make the rules. After all, if a traffic cop tells you that you can't park somewhere, you can't say "It's fine!" and not get a ticket.

So, those settings should be set in your Phabricator config. You can [configure Phabricator in multiple locations](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/advanced_configuration/), but the best place is from the web interface. You should be able to find them under the Differential settings.

Comment: This answer does not really give an answer about how to fix the problem. It's just an hint. It could be improved.